# Datetime issue with stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

The following code doesn't appear to run when executed by code:

Stored procedure snippet:

[Click to view full SP](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:2371)

```
 AND (@month_ref = 81201 
      AND tsks.grouping_ref = @grouping_ref 
      AND ts.start_dtm BETWEEN convert(datetime, '2011-11-28') 
                           AND convert(datetime,'2012-01-01')
     )
  OR (@month_ref = 81202 
      AND tsks.grouping_ref = @grouping_ref 
      AND ts.start_dtm BETWEEN convert(datetime,'2012-01-02') 
                           AND convert(datetime,'2012-01-29')
     )...
```

Server setup:

SQL Server is setup as:

- Language: English (United States)

And Windows Server region and language are set to:

- English (United States)

Our test server is set up for British English and the stored procedure appears to work just fine. I have a feeling the customer setup doesn't like the dates.

DB design / data

`ts.start_dtm` looks like this in the database:

- datatype - datetime

  ```
  2011-04-01 00:00:00.000
  ```

So its setup as - `YEAR | MONTH | DATE`

My stored procedure is hardcoding the `start_dtm` as `'2012-01-02'` which is also in the same format.

Can you help me please?

The problem is the website fails when it tries to run the stored Procedure. The issue was the data conversion. I had to assign the format of date conversion.

Comment: What happens if you just skip the convert stuff?

Comment: My issue will still remain... :(

Comment: You haven't actually said what error/problem you're getting - could you update the question to add this?

Comment: Are you saying the british setup works? `set language british; select cast('2011-11-28' as datetime)` should fail, `us_english` should succeed

Comment: Actually, the `YYYY-MM-DD` format does **NOT** work in SQL Server - e.g. with "British English". You'll need to use `YYYYMMDD` instead (**no dashes!**) to be truly language-independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need an explicit conversion on the dates at all. This is ISO8601 format, so the database should understand it straight off:

```
ts.start_dtm Between '2011-11-28' AND '2012-01-01'
```

If you need to convert them, specify what format you are using for the strings:

```
ts.start_dtm Between convert(datetime,'2011-11-28', 120) AND convert(datetime,'2012-01-01', 120)
```

Comment: The 120 is explained in the table in this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: This fixed the issue. I would still like to know why I required 120 when the format was already ISO standard? I see that 120 refers to "ODBC canonical - yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss(24h)"

Comment: @sp-1986: When you use `convert` to convert a string to date it has a default format, so by not specifying a format you implicitly told the method to try to parse the string as the `mon dd yyyy` format.

Comment: @Guffa: i see so by providing the 120 format year | month | date it converted correctly. Thank you sooo much learned alot today!

Comment: Actually, the `YYYY-MM-DD` format does **NOT** work in SQL Server - you'll need to use `YYYYMMDD` instead (**no dashes!**).

Comment: @marc_s: Funny, I use it all the time.

Comment: @Guffa: works just fine on most settings - just not on British English (ask gbn!)